# How to calculate the partitions of a concrete number?

Tags: integer-partitions

This might be a super stupid question, but my math courses are long gone and I am stuck completely solving some math puzzles for fun. Just as a hobby, no homework involved.

I want to calculate the number of ways N coins can be partitioned. I have learned that there is an extra section of [number theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function) for this and Euler was involved too, of course.

I can calculate *the generalized pentagonal numbers* using

$$
g_k = k(3k-1)/2
$$

but I have no clue how to calculate an actual value for $P(n)$. I see a lot of endless series but no solution. Could someone point to to some resources on how to work actually with these?

Comment: This is essentially a sub-question of [How To Apply and Understand the Generating Function for Number Partitioning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2707719/how-to-apply-and-understand-the-generating-function-for-number-partitioning), and I think that my answer there also covers everything that's asked here.

Comment: Perfect! That’s very helpful.